# How do I pass data into an detailView?

Tags: uitableview, ios4

I have got an `tableView`, so when the cell is tapped it diverts to a DetailViewController. But it doesn´t have any data in it, such as images or text. How do I pass this data to my DetailView?

Code for controllers:

.h file

> @interface Sushi : NSObject {
>     IBOutlet UILabel *sushiDescription;
>     IBOutlet UIImageView *sushiPicture; }
>
> @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet
>   UILabel *sushiDescription; @property
>   (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet
>   UIImageView *sushiPicture;
>
> @end

.m file

> @implementation Sushi
>
> @synthesize sushiDescription,
>   sushiPicture;
>
> -(void)dealloc {  [sushiDescription release];     [sushiPicture release];
>       [super dealloc]; }
>
> @end

Comment: one more thing, I am a beginner so please go in depth when you answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1338028/pass-data-to-object-of-uiviewcontroller-on-iphone, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1174285/cocoa-touch-uiviewcontroller-properties-and-class-design, etc...

Comment: thanks, but I have read Learning iPhone Programming by Oreily, chapter: TableView Based Apps. And I just want a simpler tutorial on how to do what it says in Oreily´s book.

Comment: What have you tried?  What specifically are you having difficulty with from the book's example?  Give some specifics about your case.  What data are your table view's cells showing?  What does the DetailViewController need to know to show the detail?

Comment: I don't have that book so I don't know what technique it's showing.  There are many ways to pass data.  If you give some code from the example or your didSelectRowAtIndexPath method, people might be able to give a good answer.  Generally, I prefer to add properties to the detail view controller that the main controller sets before presenting the detail view controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For sample do like this,

1) Store any value ex:the indexpath.row vale in appdelegate

2)In DetailViewController's viewDidLoad access the value and display it accordingly

Comment: What you want to display in detailViewController?

Comment: Try this sample code...   http://www.iphonesdkarticles.com/2009/01/uitableview-loading-detail-view.html

Comment: I want to display a image, description and I have already got the title.

Comment: Use multiple UIControllers UIImageView and two UILabels... Then update their values accordingly in ViewDidLoad

Comment: do you mean UIViewControllers instead of UIControllers?

Comment: No...place these three controllers(one UIImageView and two UILabels), assign IBOutlets to all...

Comment: This is what I have done: I made an object (also made h and m file of the object) in my detailView and added my outlets (for UIImageView and UILabel). Then I connected them to the ImageView and UILabel. Now how do I update them?

Comment: u r retrieving your values from array?

Comment: no, I am trying to find some possibilities for passing data to my detailView. I found that plist were a good way to go, does anybody know how to handle my problem with plists?